# "You're s**t" vs "You ain't s**t"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

"You're shit" vs "You ain't shit"
what do these two phrases mean? Are they interchangeable? if yes then when?

Comment: You could easily solve this problem by looking up the meanings of the _are_ and _ain't._

Comment: Here, it's quite possible that 'ain't' is short for 'ain't even'.

Comment: I remember a song from the 1980s which went "My girl is red-hot; your girl ain't doodley-squat". Much to be deplored in that, of course.

Comment: -1 for gratuitous crudeness. You might just as well have compared "literal" ***You're nothing**!* with the double-negative ***You ain't nothing**!*

Comment: There could be a *bona fide* question here, if the OP said more about the contexts in which these two (otherwise contradictory) utterances might seem interchangeable. The comment by StuartF, below the answer, hints at what the question is probably about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**“You ain't shit”**

- "You are nothing compared to me"
- "You are worthless"
- "You amount to nothing"

**“You're shit”**

- "You're bad/terrible/awful (at this)"
- "You are (literally) a turd"

The main difference here is that "You ain't shit" usually implicates the victim of this verbal abuse with some form of inferiority whereas "You're shit" is mostly just a simple insult.

Comment: Shit, like many swear words, can mean something good ("it's the shit", "hot shit") or bad.